# Enable :target element state via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I ran into the problem that some URL fragment doesn't scroll to the HTML element with that id. This is because the HTML is added via js. Scrolling the element into view can be done relatively easily with `element.scrollTo()`. But any styling targeting `:target` doesn't work.

So it seems I also need to enable the `:target` element state with JS. I did that in Firefox with the following simple line of code:

```js
location.hash = location.hash;
```

Because this also scrolls the viewport in a way that's not likable, I needed some more code, to get something along these lines:

```js
let element = document.getElementById(location.hash.substring(1));

if (element) {
    // Enable the element state without changing scroll position.
    let scrollY = window.scrollY;
    location.hash = location.hash;
    window.scrollTo({top: scrollY});

    // Smooth scroll the element into view.
    element.scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth', block: 'center'});
}
```

This works beautifully in Firefox, however the `:target` styling is not applied in Chrome. How to force Chrome to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I've found a workaround. Apparently Chrome doesn't trigger the relevant codepath *unless* the value of `location.hash` actually changes. So this does work:

```js
let element = document.getElementById(location.hash.substring(1));

if (element) {
    // Enable the element state without changing scroll position.
    let scrollY = window.scrollY;
    let hash = location.hash;
    location.hash = '';
    location.hash = hash;
    window.scrollTo({top: scrollY});

    // Smooth scroll the element into view.
    element.scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth', block: 'center'});
}
```